# Bootstrap 3 dropdown does not update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to populate a bootstrap 3 dropdown from mysql. That is working fine the first time. I add more rows to mysql they do not show in the dropdown. But if I refresh my page the rows shows in my dropdown. I also tried to show an alert but that it is showing only the first time so the code is not even called the second time.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
async: false,
url: 'update_dropdown.php',
cache: false,
success: function(data)
    {
    $("#dropdown").empty(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
        $("#dropdown").append("<li><a href='#' onclick='item()'><i class='fa fa-folder-open fa-fw'></i> "+data[i]+"</a></li>"); 
        }
    }             
});
```

Comment: Which second time ? Your ajax request is only called once in the code you provide.

Comment: I managed to solve it. My code was not called twice. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-init your dropdown once its filled in ajax success handler as follows:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
async: false,
url: 'update_dropdown.php',
cache: false,
success: function(data)
    {
        $("#dropdown").empty(); 
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            $("#dropdown").append("<li><a href='#' onclick='item()'><i class='fa fa-folder-open fa-fw'></i> "+data[i]+"</a></li>"); 
        }
        $("#dropdown").dropdown(); //re-init dropdown
    }             
});
```